# SQL Server 2016 Powershell: Restore-SqlDatabase with -ReplaceDatabase and -RelocateFile

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, restore, powershell

We have a several-node SQL Server 2016 AlwaysOn cluster, and have a need to move databases from one node/Availability Group to another quite often, so I'm trying to automate the process.

To add database to secondary replica, I need to prepare it first, i.e. backup primary, create new one on secondary, restore backup to secondary. The problem is that often the paths (local drives) do not match, for instance:

- PRIMARY: D:\Databases\db.mdf, D:\Logs\db_log.ldf
- SECONDARY: E:\Databases\db.mdf, E:\Logs\db_log.ldf

I'm trying to write a PoSh script, assuming that I have to create new database on SECONDARY server first, and came up with the following:

```
$SQLQuery = "CREATE DATABASE [$Database] ON PRIMARY ( NAME = N'$Database', FILENAME = N'$DestinationDatabaseFile' , SIZE = 1024MB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024MB ) LOG ON ( NAME = N'$LogName', FILENAME = N'$DestinationLogFile' , SIZE = 1024MB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024MB )"
Invoke-Sqlcmd2 -ServerInstance $DestinationServer -Database "master" -Query $SQLQuery

$RelocateData = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile($Database, $DestinationDatabaseFile)
$RelocateLog = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile($LogName, $DestinationLogFile)

Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $DestinationServer -Database $Database -BackupFile $LogBackupFile -ReplaceDatabase -NoRecovery -RelocateFile @($RelocateData,$RelocateLog)
```

As far as I understand on restore I need to relocate the files ( -RelocateFile ), and also replace the database ( -ReplaceDatabase ). The error I'm getting is:

> Restore-SqlDatabase : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'db' database.

Servers are of the same version, databases of same compatibility levels.

Perhaps somebody could suggest a way around?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm just going to give a word of warning here - by not having the files in the same location on the secondary as they are on the primary, should you add a new file on that primary then the AG will break until such time as you perform another backup and restore.

Comment: Nic, thanks for your imput. Perhaps i failed to elaborate, but what i'm trying to achieve is adding a database to AG. And the problem is that the local paths (drives) differ, and can't be the same, unfortunately.

Comment: I understand your need, I just want to ensure that you are aware of the risk involved in not having common file locations.

Comment: As regards the issue itself, I'm not sure why you are creating a database on the secondary at all. Just restore the database from the backup with the relocate file commands.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.  Look into [DBATools.io](https://dbatools.io/) as it's a great PowerShell cmdlet library that does this and more.

Comment: Nic, thank you for your advice! Found a solution, will paste below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked:

```
$RelocateData = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile($Database, $DestinationDatabaseFile)
$RelocateLog = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile($LogName, $DestinationLogFile)
Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $DestinationServer -Database $Database -BackupFile $DatabaseBackupFile -ReplaceDatabase -NoRecovery -RelocateFile @($RelocateData,$RelocateLog)
Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $DestinationServer -Database $Database -BackupFile $LogBackupFile -RestoreAction 'Log' -NoRecovery
```